# open input type=month programmatically

Tags: jquery, html

I have one button and one input of type month.

On click of button I want to open month popup. I am trying it with trigger of jquery but it is not working.

Fiddle for the question is http://jsfiddle.net/epfk5ya6/2/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#openMonth").on("click", function() {
        $("#month").trigger("click");
        $("#month").focus();
   });
});
```

Comment: It's unfortunately not as simple as that... Because it's an input, it doesn't have the dropdown (That's in the Shadow DOM I think). I may have something that could do it - i'll get back to you!

Comment: Ok - it didn't work - we needed a select to open when a user started typing (not as simple as you'd expect)

But what I did do, I've added to your JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/epfk5ya6/3/ - perhaps that could give a headstart? Sorry I couldn't help further

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite long since asked now...but for those as I that actually didn't get it...just try

```
document.getElementById('month').showPicker();
```

got from https://www.stefanjudis.com/blog/new-on-the-web-programmatically-open-a-native-date-picker/